# How to make time series file using pandas

Tags: python, time, numpy, pandas, series

I made time series generator using python.
The source code is here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7010817

But I have trouble with date counting and save data into same file.
The required result is like the following:

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00, 0.1212...
2013-01-01 00:00:01, 1.1212...
...
2013-01-01 00:XX:XX, 2.1231...
2013-01-02 00:00:00, 0.0000...
2013-01-02 00:00:01, 0.8256...
...
2013-01-02 00:XX:XX, 1.5890...
...
```

But actual result is the following:

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00, 0.1212...
2013-01-01 00:00:01, 1.1212...
...
2013-01-01 00:XX:XX, 2.1231...
```

Only data of last day is saved. How can I fix the problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The number of periods defined in your index is `len(x)`, which is the same as your `duration` variable. Now, I can see that in the Gist  you have shared, `duration` is 100. This means that your index shall contain time starting from midnight of 1st Jan 2013 to the next 100 seconds.
Thus, the code is behaving correctly.

You may wish to alter duration or maybe keep `freq` as a day to get more than 1 day worth data.
The following is the result of `head` on the CSV produced if I alter the `freq.` to day (D).

```
nipun@nipun-Satellite-L850:~/Desktop$ head temp.csv 
2013-01-01,0.5610715563428571
2013-01-02,1.46599572922606
2013-01-03,1.6778167560314936
2013-01-04,2.62905543843325
2013-01-05,3.369346748155469
2013-01-06,3.852764462138
2013-01-07,4.834465391540452
2013-01-08,5.411356890867407
2013-01-09,6.30042970400768
2013-01-10,7.240255999695465
```